# How to get Keycloak client_id and client_secret from server to client

Tags: rest, api, keycloak

Actually I have a server (customer server) from where I would like to fetch some parameters and its values for NE configuration through REST API.

To achieve the above task I need to follow the below steps:

1)  Creating a Keycloak client id and generating a client secret for the respective client id created. (One time step can be done manually in Keycloak admin GUI)
2)  Using the  client id and client secret - generating an access token.
3)  Using access token and retrieving the expected parameters

Here I have found the methods and API URLs to get the expected parameters and its values (Step 3 is done), But to make the initial connection (Step 2) between my server (Client-From where I am making the REST calls) and customer server (Server-Which responds to my API calls) I need to find some method to exchange the client id and client secret from source server to client server.

My development environment has some limitation that I cannot directly use the client id and client secret hard coded in it.

So, My doubts are

1) In general will the customer shares the client id and client secret to developers to get connected to the authentication server ? 
2) Will the client id and client secret gets stored anywhere in the server (some default location) so that i can login to the server and get these data directly to generate the access token?
3) Is there another way to get the client id and client secret from source server.

Comment: I need to ask a few questions to understand clearly your question.
* You have a server (customer server), and calls it's rest end point from client (your from) am i right ?. 
* does your client has  access token ?
* do you want to authenticate (validate access token of client) client request on server side (customer server) ?

Comment: * You have a server (customer server), and calls it's rest end point from client (your from) am i right ?. 

(Ans) Yes i want to call customer's end point API from my server.


* Does your client has access token ? 

(Ans) Yes there is a access token but we used to generate it after logging into the customer server (as we perform some other operation on the customer server which needs ssh login and it is passwordless access already)
* Do you want to authenticate(validate access token of client)client request on server side
(Ans) Yes I wanted to be authenticated by the customer server.

Comment: you must have a realm on keycloak, (i will call it with realmX). 
Caller server (server which calls customer server.) was registered to realmX as client by you. (realm clients). If customer server uses keycloak as authentication provider, you need to register customer server to keycloak as realmX client. When you call customer server with access token (which generated for caller server) will validated by keycloak. If both server are registered under same realm (realmX), they can validate tokens of each others.

Comment: we do keep clientId and clientSecret injected using standard spring boot params in to application.properties, each environment/client has own clientSecret, don't know better way